# Problem following links of vim's doc (:help) on the terminal

Tags: key-bindings

I'm having some trouble reading vim's documentation on the terminal because I can't follow the links that are given.

I quote:

> Jump to a subject:  Position the cursor on a tag (e.g. |bars|) and
>   hit CTRL-].

The problem is that i'm using a spanish keyboard where the "+" and the "]" are on the same button so when I hit CTRL-], I make a zoom.

Can I map the CTRL-] to any other keys somehow or is there any other option?

Comment: Did you try anything? E.g. `nnoremap <leader>h <c-]>`

Comment: I use the following mapping: `nnoremap <buffer> <cr> <c-]>` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/help.vim`.

Comment: I've placed the mappings in my ~/.vimrc file and it still doesn't work

Comment: Maybe CTRL-Shift-]?

Comment: It works fine. Thanks, I can jump now from tag to tag easily. @blm

Comment: It's a personal choice, but I chose to adopt an EN QWERTY layout for coding, as some keys like \, [, ] etc. are easier to reach. (I'm French).

Comment: That's definitely true but I'm using a laptop and I prefer using its keyboard ( I know I can change the keyboard language easily but It's quite confusing) @JoshRomRock

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option (if you don't mind a bit of typing) is to type `:tag tagname` and press enter.  This is exactly equivalent to Ctrl-] according to `:help CTRL-]`.

If you use this, please note that you can use tab completion just as when typing `:help topic` commands, and you can use Ctrl-D to list the possible autocompletions of what you've typed so far.

I admit this isn't much of an alternative, but it's worth knowing.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is using clicking on the tag, if `set mouse=a` is on.

Comment: It does work but I'd prefer not having to use the mouse.

Answer (score 3):

*For those having french AZERTY keyboard, try*

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>$</kbd> (<kbd>$,£,¤</kbd> key)

Comment: > For those having french AZERTY keyboard, try > CTRL + $ ($,£,¤ key) How come??

Comment: @Abd I think he refers to the position where ] is located on a QWERTY keyboard.

Comment: Yes this is the real reason ! At the time I remember trying random combinations on my keyboard to find this...

Comment: For me on an AZERTY Apple keyboard, the `$` and `£`/backtick keys are different. `CTRL+$` did nothing, but `CTRL+£` was the winner. Thanks for this, I never understood why the default shortcut was not working and how to get around this.